# Code to Print List Loop to PDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vba, printing

I have a spreadsheet that creates a graph and chart using a list selection. I have figured out the code to get the file to loop through the list and print each selection, however, I have not been able to figure out how to print it to PDF as opposed to my printer. Can anyone help me out? I want one PDF file with all graphs/charts. Bonus points if the code automatically leaves out pages with no data.

This is the code I have in my file:

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Lists").Range("a2:a122")
For Each cell In rng.Cells
Sheets("Summary").Range("b3").Value = cell.Value
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://www.printandshare.info) commercial solution, it has file printer options to create PDF files and it can [automatically remove pages](http://www.printandshare.info/overview/eco) based on conditions that you configure.
I'm not sure if it is possible otherwise.